# Carburetor Heat Required on Carburetor equipped GA aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, carbheat

Is Carburetor Heat Required (by FAA Certification regulations) on Carburetor equipped GA aircraft?
If not, what (if any) certified carburetor-equipped GA aircraft do NOT have Carburetor Heat installed ?

Answer (score 2):

Carb heat is not specifically required by regulation. What is required by the following rule is a means to prevent ice accretion:

> **14 CFR 33.35 Fuel and induction system.**
>
> (b) The intake passages of the engine through which air or fuel in
>   combination with air passes for combustion purposes must be designed
>   and constructed to minimize the danger of ice accretion in those
>   passages. The engine must be designed and constructed to permit the
>   use of a means for ice prevention.

Carb heat is the most common solution, but alternate solutions may be acceptable.